# SSL connection using HttpUrlConnection in android application

Tags: android, http, httpconnection

I'm migrating an existing project from using the `org.apache.http.legacy` library to `HttpUrlConnection`, because the first is deprecated in android 6.0
In fact i'm using a SSL connection through the class `SSLSocketFactory`, the project has customized this class but that's not important. What i want to know is how can i create a SSL socket using `HttpUrlConnection` library. The solution i want must give me the ability to set my certificate.

Comment: With "set my certificate" do you mean client or server certificate? In case you mean server certificate read https://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html section "Using your own trust store: HttpsURLConnection".

Comment: it's stored in my resources in the android app !

Comment: If your comment should be response to my comment I don't understand it. I was asking what certificate you use: A client certificate with private key or a (self-signed?) server certificate.

Comment: a client certificate with private key ;)